# Transform value of PHP form on submit

Tags: php, get, payment

i'm setting up donate option on a website using przelewy24.pl. They have this startup template to send values by $_GET method to their website.

Everything works fine exept the amount field. Przelewy24 needs a gr amount (like cents) and i would like for the donor to type in integer in full zł (like $).

If the upper is not clear - when i type 100 in the field, it sends it to przelewy24 as 100 gr, whitch will be 1 zł.
I need to know how could i format the amount sent to them as in simple calculation - when 100 is typed, get sends 10000. (x*100)

The form used is shown below. The quick-start guide is avaliable [here](https://www.przelewy24.pl/storage/app/media/pobierz/Instalacja/przelewy24_specyfikacja_uproszczona_1.00.pdf), but only in polish

```
<form method="get" action="https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_id_sprzedawcy" value="TWOJ_ID">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_crc" value="KLUCZ_ZAKUPU">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_return_url" value="TWOJASTRONA.PL">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_language" value="pl">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">Nazwa produktu:</td> 
<td>
<input type="text" name="z24_nazwa" value="Opłata za rezerwację NR: 04/234/A3953">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Dodatkowy opis:</td>
<td>
<textarea name="z24_opis" style="width:250px">Dodatkowe informacje... 
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Do zapłaty:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="z24_kwota"></td><!--KWOTA W GROSZACH-->
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="zapłać z przelewy24.pl">
</form>
```

Comment: Without any code, It is impossible to really help you. Just a couple of hints:
- from the action form, you are sending data collection directly to przelewy24 -> no format adjust possible in php (with javascript you can easily multiply the value on submit but, as a donor, I would consider the change of the amount donated as a fraud).

Comment: @Eineki przelewy24 is a payment provider, so user will see correct amount of money and user propably will get sms with details from their bank before accepting the payment

Comment: I'm not saying it is, just that an user would be confused seeing an amount change just after the form submit. The hidden field proposed below it is a viable solution to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple Javascript code.
You need to capture the value from input, transform it, and put the value on `input hidden`:

```js
function formatMoney(e) {
 document.getElementById('z24_kwota').value = (!isNaN(e.target.value) ? e.target.value : 0) * 100

 // just to debug.. you can remove this line:
 document.getElementById('final_value').innerHTML = document.getElementById('z24_kwota').value
}
```

```html
<form method="get" action="https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_id_sprzedawcy" value="TWOJ_ID">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_crc" value="KLUCZ_ZAKUPU">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_return_url" value="TWOJASTRONA.PL">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_language" value="pl">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">Nazwa produktu:</td> 
<td>
<input type="text" name="z24_nazwa" value="Opłata za rezerwację NR: 04/234/A3953">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Dodatkowy opis:</td>
<td>
<textarea name="z24_opis" style="width:250px">Dodatkowe informacje... 
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Do zapłaty:</td>
<td>
 <input type="hidden" name="z24_kwota" id="z24_kwota">
 <input type="text" onkeyup="formatMoney(event)"></td><!--KWOTA W GROSZACH-->
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="zapłać z przelewy24.pl">
</form>

<!-- you can remove this line: -->
Final Value: <span id="final_value"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value before submitting the form like below,

```
<form method="get" id="myform" action="https://sklep.przelewy24.pl/zakup.php">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_id_sprzedawcy" value="TWOJ_ID">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_crc" value="KLUCZ_ZAKUPU">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_return_url" value="TWOJASTRONA.PL">
<input type="hidden" name="z24_language" value="pl">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="right">Nazwa produktu:</td> 
<td>
<input type="text" name="z24_nazwa" value="Opłata za rezerwację NR: 04/234/A3953">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Dodatkowy opis:</td>
<td>
<textarea name="z24_opis" style="width:250px">Dodatkowe informacje... 
</textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Do zapłaty:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="z24_kwota"></td><!--KWOTA W GROSZACH-->
</tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="zapłać z przelewy24.pl">
</form>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstSubmit = false;
    $('#myform').on('submit',function(e){  
        if(!firstSubmit){     
            e.preventDefault();        
            firstSubmit = true;
            var amount = parseInt($('input[name=z24_kwota]').val());
            $('input[name=z24_kwota]').val(amount*100);
            $('#myform').trigger('submit');        
        }
    })
</script>
```

Note: I have given an id to the form as **myform**